# How to fix imageview over linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to display an image over linearlayout and
[This is how my layout should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tvgw.jpg)

I created my layout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/anim_image"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:src="@drawable/success_icon" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/anim_layout"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/grayBackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Success"
        android:textColor="@color/lightFont"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Check you email for booking\nconfirmation We'll see you soon"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="@color/progressWhite"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How should I change my code to place imageview on top of Linearlayout as shown in image, help me to get exact view that I wanted

Comment: Use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="10dp">



<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/anim_layout"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:background="@color/grayBackground"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Success"
    android:textColor="@color/lightFont"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Check you email for booking\nconfirmation We'll see you soon"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    android:text="OK"
    android:textColor="@color/progressWhite"
    android:textSize="16dp" />


</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/anim_image"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:src="@drawable/success_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nesting the LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout ... worked for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

try this using **RelativLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp">



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/anim_layout"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/grayBackground"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Success"
        android:textColor="@color/lightFont"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Check you email for booking\nconfirmation We'll see you soon"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="@color/progressWhite"
        android:textSize="16dp" />


</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/anim_image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/success_icon" />
```